# How to move txt file to other folder?

Tags: c#, file

I try to write a console app C# to move my etxt files to another folder. 
The functions just copies certain .txt files from folder A to folder AA

```
string source = "C:\\A\\ResultClassA.txt";
File.Move(Source, "C:\\AA");
```

But its always giving this error message:

Access to the path is denied.

Troubleshooting tips:
Make sure you have sufficient privileges to access this resource.
If you are attempting to access a file, make sure it is not ReadOnly.
Get general help for this exception.

Do i really need to set my folder A and folder B to "NOT ReadOnly" attribute before "File.move" code are execuse? and set to read only back after success moved?

Thanks.
By Hero .

Comment: does the folder `C:\AA` exist? File.Move just moves the file, it will not create the directory. It will also fail if the `source` file is in use or inaccesible.

Comment: if you would have a try/catch around the code you could tell more details about the exception, also notice in your example the Source in second line should be lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the full path and make sure the path `C:\AA` exists

```
string source = "C:\\A\\ResultClassA.txt";
File.Move(Source, "C:\\AA\\ResultClassA.txt");
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx) for good sample

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        string path2 = @"c:\temp2\MyTest.txt";
        try 
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This statement ensures that the file is created,
                // but the handle is not kept.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
            }

            // Ensure that the target does not exist.
            if (File.Exists(path2)) 
            File.Delete(path2);

            // Move the file.
            File.Move(path, path2);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was moved to {1}.", path, path2);

            // See if the original exists now.
            if (File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The original file still exists, which is unexpected.");
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The original file no longer exists, which is expected.");
            }           

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lol welcome. don't forget to tick one of the answers if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Hero, you are moving from a file name to a folder name, try to specify a file name with extension inside the `C:\AA` folder.

does AA exist already on C ?